# Superfish 3rd level dropdown size

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, web, superfish

Im currently using the [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) menu for our website. The issue Is that i have a lot of list items on the 3rd level so the drop down goes down pretty long. Is there a way i can make the 3rd level dropdown shorter without making the 1st and 2nd levels shorter?

[Here is an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWUKd.jpg)